# Pass data to child React component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a very simple React app. Im trying to pass data from myArray in Parent.jsx to Child.jsx

Child.jsx:

```
    import React from 'react';

    export const Child = (props) => {
      return <h1>{ myArray[0].name }</h1>;
    };
```

Parent.jsx:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {Child} from './child';

    export const Parent = (props) => {

        const myArray = [
          {
            name: "tom smith",
            age: "99"
          },
          {
            name: "alex",
            age: "12"
          }
        ];

        return <div>
            <h1>Parent heading</h1>
                <Child />
                <h2>Parent footer</h2>
            </div>;

    };
```

app.jsx:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {Parent} from './parent';

    export default class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Row />
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parent component needs to pass the array to the child component.

e.g.

```
   const myArray = [
      {
        name: "tom smith",
        age: "99"
      },
      {
        name: "alex",
        age: "12"
      }
    ];

return <div>
    <h1>Parent heading</h1>
        <Child childArray={myArray} />
        <h2>Parent footer</h2>
    </div>;
```

};

Then in the child component

```
export const Child = (props) => {
  return <h1>{ props.childArray[0].name}</h1>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

import React from 'react';

```
export const Child = (props) => {
  return <h1>{ props. myArray[0].name }</h1>;
};
```